# What one line code algorithm in python 3 will give such result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing

The test question is in the form of a fill in the blanks and this question shows part of the code and requires me to provide the code the programmer must have entered to give the result printed in a single line statement.

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 4, 1, 7, 8]
#[fill in the blank in one line]
print(a)
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7 8]
```

The result is the list shown rearranged with no duplicates in it.

Comment: Assuming this is homework or a quiz, and not wanting to give too much away - you want a "sorted" list of "distinct" values -- run with that. Also, you could cheat and use slicing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `sort`ing the list after removing duplicates, by converting to `set`?

```
>>> a = sorted(set(a))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a one-line statement that fixes up the specific list you were given, you could use:

```
del a[6:9]
```

This deletes three values from the list, and leaves the rest in order. It will probably be quite a lot faster than sorting or using a `set`, but it's much less general. It works for the specific list given, but won't produce similar output if the unwanted values are located somewhere else.

Comment: ohh i see.. i initially found out i could go with the set method although i haven't tried your stated method yet. thank you